# Google OAuth Application Verification without Website

Tags: google-api, youtube-api, google-oauth, youtube-data-api, verification

I am using the OAuth Functionality in a local Console Program to request the Videos for my Youtube Channel and upload Videos to Youtube.

For the Example which Google gives OAuth is used to authenticate to be able to retrieve the wanted data. But the Videos I am uploading keep getting put to private because my API Service is not verified.

Now I want to verify my API Service but I dont have a website for it so I can't provide any links for data security information or the main page of it. I mean it is a desktop app which only I am using and which is not meant to be publicly available.

How can I fulfill the verification process without any option to provide this informations?

Answer (score 1):

## private videos

If you check the top of the page for [Videos: insert](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert)  you will find that your videos are being uploaded private because your app has not been though a security audit.

[image]

## app verification

In order to apply for app verification there are a number of urls that you need to supply

[image]

You will need to register a domain and claim it in web masters and then you will be able to add them.

If you want to be able to upload public videos via the YouTube Data api your app needs to be verified.  In order to verify it you need to be able to show the TOS, privacy policy and the application home page. There is no way around this even if its a desktop app. Even if its single user you still need to do this.

I have a video which shows you what you need to know to verify your app.

- [What you need to know about Google verification in 2021.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lzIuNmNX9N8)