# Uploading public videos with OAuth API without a domain/website

Tags: youtube-api

I'm having the same issue as the one described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71043953/18214605) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71015647/18214605) question. The OAuth consent screen page says "**Verification not required**" but when I upload videos they get "locked as private". According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71044676/18214605), a domain is needed in order to verify the app and fix this, but I don't have a website related to the application.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71015726/18214605) explains adding a domain in order to get verified and upload public videos but I'm afraid the domain and website I do own are completely unrelated to the content I'd upload to the YouTube channel. So is there a way of using the API to upload public videos without owning a website/domain or can I use an unrelated website that I own?

Answer (score 0):

At the top of the [Video.insert](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert) page  you will see it states.

[image]

Audit is not verification, these are two different things. You need to apply for an audit. [YouTube API Services - Audit and Quota Extension Form](https://support.google.com/youtube/contact/yt_api_form)